# When to use "by" or "to"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Should I use "by" or "to" in the following?

If you create the image for the user and it's approved, it's then visible and usable **by** all members.

OR:

If you create the image for the user and it's approved, it's then visible and usable **to** all members.

By the way, the long-form is "If you create the image for the user and it's approved, it's then visible to (and usable by) all members.". I was just trying to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: You could rephrase the sentence and bypass the problem altogether: *If you create the image for the user and it's approved, all members will find it visible and usable.* In fact, that sounds better to me anyway.

Comment: _Visible_ takes _to_ and _usable_ takes _by_. So you can't delete either prepositions by conjunction reduction, since they're not identical. Thus the solution is to delete only the repeated object and leave the two prepositions: _... then it's visible to and usable by all members_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that *visible* and *usable* are not the same. Normally, you would use *visible to* and *usable by*:

> stars visible to the naked eye
>   [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visible#examples)

Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visible%20to%2C%20visible%20by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvisible%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvisible%20by%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=usable%20by%2C%20usable%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cusable%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cusable%20to%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

However, since *visible by* is also acceptable, I would go with the less awkward combination:

> visible and usable by all members.

rather than:

> visible to and usable by all members.

---

I suppose:

> visible and usable to all members.

is also grammatically correct, but it doesn't have exactly the same meaning: something is either usable or unusable (worthless) **to** me. If something is made available to me so I can use it, it becomes usable **by** me.

Answer (score 1):

According to numerous examples in Reverso.context.net we should use only 'by' here.
See one of the examples:
'Data for wood resource balances should be collected and analysis be carried out in close collaboration with the energy sector in such a way that the results be usable by all participants in the overall debate and work on renewable energy.'